# Displaying sql records in a listview

Tags: html, sqlite, listview

I have some code below:

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY date DESC', [],
                      function(transaction, result) {
                      if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                      for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                      var row = result.rows.item(i);
                      $('#records').append('<li><a href ="#">' + 'item1: ' + row['row1'] + '<br>' + 'item2: ' + row['row2'] + '<br>' + 'item3: ' + row['row3'] + '<br>' + 'item4: ' + row['row4'] + '</a></li>');

                                      $( "#records" ).listview().listview("refresh");
                                      }
                                      }
                                      },errorHandler);
},errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

As you can see, each time I input a record, all of this is displayed as a list item in a listview.  But my problem is, the part where I have appended a href = "#".  This is to make each list item linked, but I want a link to a different location depending on the record.  Right now, each record would link to the same place.

Is there a way to put that href somewhere else so that it can depend on each list item?

the HTML where the list appears is below:

```
 <div data-role = "content">

       <ul id = "records"></ul>

 </div>
```

Please let me know if the question isn't clear, I'll try and make it clearer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you can always change href, like that maybe

```
$("#records li a").each(function() {
  var s =  $(this).text();    
  if (s == "text1") {
       $(this).attr("href","href1");
  }
  else if (s == "text2") {
       $(this).attr("href","href2");
  }
```

});

might be some syntax errors above, im not jquery expert, i wanted to show general idea